# Bot authentication with azure app service EasyAuth

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-authentication

I am struggling to get my teams bot to work with my azure app service with Authentication enabled.

Here is my setup:
I have a teams bot that reacts to some events in the team. I also have an azure web app that has an endpoint `/api/messages` that listens to bot messages. There is an Azure Bot Channels Registration that wires those two together.

It all works fine until I enable EasyAuth in my web app to authenticate with Azure AD (I need this because there are other endpoints in this web app that need to be secured). With authentication in web app enabled, bot messages do not reach the web app, and I cannot find any errors in logs either.

I tried to add different OAuth Connection Settings in my Bot Channels Registration, and also Allowed Token Audiences in auth settings in web app, but I haven't found a setup that works yet.

Could someone please tell me how this should be configured? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check if this [sample](https://github.com/cgillum/easyauth) helps.

Answer (score 1):

please refer to Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization (Easy Auth) guidance: https://github.com/cgillum/easyauth

The admin API setting: https://github.com/cgillum/easyauth/wiki

Advanced Application Settings: https://github.com/cgillum/easyauth/wiki/Advanced-Application-Settings

If you need more details, I would highly suggest you go through the official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization

Comment: Thank you, but this is too vague. I have a general understanding on how the EasyAuth works. What I cannot configure is to how to expose the message endpoint that bot uses while EasyAuth is enabled. The calls from the bot are not reaching the service in this case. I need to know what exactly needs to be set in either advanced application settings in app service, or in bot channels registration settings

Comment: @Taras - same thing i am looking for, if anyone can help pls?